# How to publish python packages to internal artifactory in poetry using a token

Tags: python, python-3.x, artifactory, python-poetry

I am using `poetry` version 1.1.6 to build and publish my project to an internal artifactory.

I have provided the below command and configured the repository.

```
poetry config repositories.myrepo https://my-internal-artifactory/api/pypi/python/simple
```

How do I configure API token for an internal repository?

I tried this

```
poetry config http-basic.myrepo mytoken
```

Its still prompting for password assuming that I am providing a username and password. However, all I have is a token. I don't have a username and password.

The docs doesn't seem to provide sufficient information for private repositories using tokens,

**Note : Before poetry, we were using curl to upload to artifactory using the token.**

How do we publish to private repositories with token in poetry? Is it even possible to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The `http-basic` config is for user + password combination, you're only providing one of them.
There's another configuration setting called `pypi-token`, you probably want to use this instead (more information in the [credentials section of poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#configuring-credentials)). In your case it should be `poetry config pypi-token.myrepo mytoken`

Make sure that you haven't specified both `http-basic` and `pypi-token`, as just one of them will work - i belive poetry will check for `pypi-token` and if that is present it will use that. Just use `poetry config --unset` to remove the other config option.

My problem was I wanted to publish to *Artifactory*, where you have a token but you also have a user, in that case you need to use the `http-basic` option and specify both your user and your token as the password.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, I don't have a user..Just a token. Anyway let me try this

Comment: Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

generate a user token in artifactory for your user

manually edit the poetry auth file `~/.config/pypoetry/auth.toml`

```ini
[http-basic]
[http-basic.my-repo]
username = "USERNAME"
password = "YOUR_TOKEN"
```